# How to Benchmark Hive (Azure Interactive Query HDI 4.0)

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, tpc

Does anyone have a **working and tested as of 2020** TPC-DS or TPC-H benchmarks for Azure Interactive Query HDI 4.0 clusters, which uses Hadoop 3.x+?

I was using https://github.com/hortonworks/hive-testbench but I ran into an error trying to generate data for TPC-H and TPC-DS.

Interactive Query HDI 4.0 (Hadoop 3.1.1). What could this error be? The step that fails is when it runs the jar file.

[image: code where it fails]

```
Generating data at scale factor 100.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: 
class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem cannot access its superinterface org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.TokenAspect$TokenManagementDelegator
...
ls: `/tmp/tpch-generate/100/lineitem': No such file or directory
Data generation failed, exiting.
```

Then second question is that for TPC-DS whenever I run "large" scale factors, the failure comes during the optimization step. And it usually fails on table 17 or 18. Any ideas of what this could be?

```
INFO  : Loading data to table tpcds_bin_partitioned_orc_100.store_sales partition (ss_sold_date_sk=null) from wasb://asdasd-2020-04-16t02-32-03-034z@asdasd.blob.core.windows.net/hive/warehouse/managed/tpcds_bin_partitioned_orc_100.db/store_sales/.hive-staging_hive_2020-04-16_06-47-19_242_1371829803314907581-47/-ext-10000
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. Exception updating metastore for acid table tpcds_bin_partitioned_orc_100.store_sales with partitions [store_sales
...
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20200416064719_4aa11ffb-31c0-411f-a7ca-954c9741891d); Time taken: 1280.036 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. Exception updating metastore for acid table tpcds_bin_partitioned_orc_100.store_sales with partitions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MoveTask error is due to an internal sql database limitation. In Azure SQL Database, the incoming parameters can only have 2100 parameters and the benchmarks generate too many partitions.

```
hive.direct.sql.max.elements.values.clause=200
hive.direct.sql.max.elements.in.clause=200
```